# Angular - Route programmatically by loading component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

i have a working route in my app-routing.module.ts.
The route works, if i call it from Template like:

Template:

```
 <a href="#"
       routerLinkActive="active-link"
       [routerLink]="[{outlets: { subbaOutlet2: ['userDetails', detailsId] }}]"
    >
      Daten anzeigen
 </a>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
{
   path: 'userDetailsWrapper/:detailsId',
   component: UserDetailsContentWrapperComponent,
   children: [
    {
      path: 'userDetails/:detailsId',
      outlet: 'subbaOutlet2',
      loadChildren: () =>
        import('@project-workspace/user/feature-details-user').then(
             (m) => m.UserFeatureDetailsModule
         ),
    }],
   }
```

So if i try to call the route from the navigation component by loading like this:
I have also tried to load it from ngOnInit().

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.subscribeRouteParams = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.detailsId = params['detailsId'];
      this.router.navigate( ['userDetails', {detailsId:this.detailsId}]);
    });
}
```

Error in console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'userDetails;detailsId=22222222'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'userDetails;detailsId=22222222'
```

Any ideas how to write the call to the route from the component? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? `.navigate( ['userDetails', {detailsId:this.detailsId}]);`  should it be `.navigate( ['userDetails'], {detailsId:this.detailsId});`

Comment: Thanks for your tip! But id doesn't work.
I have also tried this:

`this.router.navigate( [{ outlets:{ subbaOutlet2: ['userDetails']}}], { queryParams: {detailsId:this.detailsId}} );`

Also the error: `Error: Cannot match any routes.`